# postitioning and sizing box with xml file in indesign

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I have got a website that makes maps out of divs, the divs location and size gets pulled out of a database and then build to size and position with jquery. Now i want to make a printable version of this aswell by exporting a xml file that i can then import into indesign to get the same result as i would in a browser window. basicly the xml file would generate the boxes and postition and scale them like the web version but then in indesign

the web version looks like this:
[image]

I have been googling to try and find a similar thing as im trying to accomplish but i cant find anything on how to build boxes in indesign and positioning and scaling them with a xml file. so if anyone could lead me in the right direction would be really appreciated

Comment: This may not work for your requirements, but I'll throw it oput just incase! If you're using a mac, you can chose to print the page, then instead of sending it to a printer just save it as a PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at InDesign's IDML capabilities. An IDML file is a package of XML files within a zipped up folder. Here are some IDML references:

[IDML File Format Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf)

[IDML Coookbook](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs5_docs/idml/idml-cookbook.pdf)

InDesign also has some XML objects that can be embedded into IDML or used with the Javascripting DOM, but I think for your case, it would be easier to try and create an IDML file directly since it's pretty easy to work with. You can also take a look at importing an IDML snippet file which includes just a piece of IDML without having to be bundled up in a zip file.

Take a look at the `Rectangle` element in particular which might be what you are looking for. I've included a sample IDML snippet file example below that creates a red rectangle when you import it. Save it in a text file with an `.idms` extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?aid style="50" type="snippet" readerVersion="6.0" featureSet="257" product="8.0(370)" ?>
<?aid SnippetType="PageItem"?>
<Document DOMVersion="8.0" Self="d">
   <Color Self="Color/u13b" Model="Process" Space="CMYK" ColorValue="0 100 100 0"/>
   <Spread Self="uc6">
      <Rectangle Self="u133" StrokeWeight="0" FillColor="Color/u13b" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 0 0">
         <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
               <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                  <PathPointArray>
                     <PathPointType Anchor="36.5 -359.5" LeftDirection="36.5 -359.5" RightDirection="36.5 -359.5" />
                     <PathPointType Anchor="36.5 -190.0" LeftDirection="36.5 -190.0" RightDirection="36.5 -190.0" />
                     <PathPointType Anchor="160.0 -190.0" LeftDirection="160.0 -190.0" RightDirection="160.0 -190.0" />
                     <PathPointType Anchor="160.0 -359.5" LeftDirection="160.0 -359.5" RightDirection="160.0 -359.5" />
                  </PathPointArray>
               </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
         </Properties>
      </Rectangle>
   </Spread>
</Document>
```

You can create further examples for yourself by making the objects in InDesign, selecting them, and then exporting them as Snippet files or IDML files.